# Conditional variance and expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Recall that we say $X$ ~ $Geometric(p)$ if $P(X=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$ for each $k=1,2,3,...$
The mean, variance, and moment generating function are
$E(X)=\frac{1}{p}$ $var(X)=\frac{1-p}{p^2}$ $M_X(s)=\frac{p}{e^{-s}-(1-p)}$

Let $N$ ~ $Geometric(p)$. Let $Y$ denote the sum of $N$ independent identically distributed random variables $X_i$ ~ $Geometric(p)$.

I have the following solution and would appreciate some input as to whether or not my work along with my answers is correct.

(a) What are 
$E(Y|N)$ $E(Y)$ $var(Y|N)$ $var(E(Y|N)$ and $var(Y)$

$$E(Y|N)=E(X_1+...+X_n|N)=\frac{1}{p}N$$
$$E(Y)=E(E(Y|N))=E(\frac{1}{p}N)=\frac{1}{p}E(N)=\frac{1}{p^2}$$
$$var(Y|N)=E(Y^2|N)-(E(Y|N))^2=\frac{1}{p^2}N-(\frac{1}{p}N)^2=\frac{N-N^2}{p^2}$$
$$var(E(Y|N))=var(\frac{1}{p}N)=\frac{1}{p}var(N)=\frac{1}{p}\frac{1-p}{p^2}=\frac{1-p}{p^3}$$
$$var(Y)=var(E(Y|N))+E(var(Y|N))=\frac{1-p}{p^3}+E(\frac{N-N^2}{p^2})=\frac{1-p}{p^3}+\frac{1}{p^2}E(N)-\frac{1}{p^2}E(N^2)=\frac{1-p}{p^3}+\frac{1}{p^2}\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{p^2}E(N^2)$$ 
$$E(N^2)=Var(N)+E(N)^2=\frac{1-p}{p^2}+\frac{1}{p^2}=\frac{2-p}{p^2}$$
$$var(Y)=\frac{1-p}{p^3}+\frac{1}{p^2}\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{p^2}\frac{2-p}{p^2}=\frac{2-p}{p^3}-\frac{2+p}{p^4}$$

(b) What is the moment generating function of $Y$?

$$M_Y(s)=E(e^{sk})=\sum_{k=1} ^\infty p(1-p)^{k-1}e^{sk}=$$

Not sure what to do from here.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** $\mathsf {Var}(N)=\mathsf E(N^2)-\mathsf E(N)^2$

**Hint 2:** $\mathsf M_Y(s) ~{=~ \mathsf E(e^{sY}) \\= \mathsf E\big(\mathsf E(e^{sY}\mid N)\big)\\=~\mathsf E\big(\mathsf E(e^{s\sum_{k=1}^N X_k}\mid N)\big)\\ =~\mathsf E\big(\prod_{k=1}^N\mathsf E(e^{sX_k})\big) \qquad\text{(why fore?)} \\ =~ \mathsf E\Big(\big(\mathsf E(e^{sX_1})\big)^N\Big)\\=~\mathsf E\big(e^{N\ln\mathsf E(e^{s X_1})}\big)\\~\vdots}$

Comment: Thank you. I used hint 1 to complete the problem. Still struggling with the second hint.

Comment: Well, what is $\mathsf E(e^{s~X_1})$?  What is $\mathsf E(e^{t~N})$?

Comment: I don't understand how you went from step 3 to step 4 (the "why fore" line.

Comment: Well, *why* can we say: $\mathsf E(\prod_{k=1}^N e^{s X_k}\mid N)=\prod_{k=1}^N  \mathsf E(e^{sX_k})$ ?